# Graph Visualization with igraph and R

Tags: r, visualization, igraph, graph-visualization

I am trying to visualize graphs in R with the igraph package. I wish to visualize graphs with the edge size being between 2000 to 70,000. The plots look like this:

[image]

This is not a nice plot as you cannot see anything. I have figured out how to take away the labels, but still you cannot see anything since the vertices are so big.

1. Can I remove the vertices and just look at the edges?

For example here is the same plot but I took the picture before it was finished. It seems that R only draws the edges before it is finished:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the vertex size to 0.

```
library(igraph)
g <- barabasi.game(100)
plot( g, vertex.size=0, vertex.label=NA, edge.arrow.size=0 )
```

[image: Sample graph]

Comment: Are there different layout algorithms to specify? I tried it out and it is exactly what I was looking for (strangely was not in the documentation). It does not look like it does in my picture above.

Comment: The plot was generated using exactly that code, nothing else.
Most of the parameters are listed in `?igraph.plotting`,
but they have to be prefixed by `vertex.` or `edge.`.
Depending on your graph, the default layout may not be the best choice
(my example was a tree -- that is much easier to plot):
you can check `?layout` for the complete list of layout algorithms.
To plot large graphs, many people use [Gephi](https://gephi.org/),
which (being interactive) may be more flexible.

Comment: With `vertex.size=0` igraph still draws some very small vertices. It is better to set the shape to `none`: `plot(..., vertex.shape="none", vertex.size=0)`.